# Как работает where?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Я понимаю, что where бежит по строкам и ищет вхождение по шаблону, но на низком уровне как это все происходит?

Вопрос от части связан с индексами, в чем разница если мы пробежим по исходной таблице по тому же столбцу и если будем искать по таблице индексов с не уникальными значениями. По сути и там и там поиск будет по всей таблице, но не затрагиваются лишние столбцы, то есть в самом SQL сначала будет поиск самого столбца и он займёт больше времени чем в индексах?

Не совсем понимаю этот момент

Я понимаю работe индексов, но не совсем понял как именно идёт поиск по таблицы на низком уровне

Comment: Если индекс это отсортированный файл, то читать придется лишь его часть, да и вообще, в большинстве  случаев, размер индекса значительно меньше размера таблицы, т.е. меньшее количество блоков диска надо прочесть

Comment: Эмм... а разве искусство писателя запросов как раз не состоит в том, чтобы понять какой запрос будет выполняться быстрее с перебором по массиву, по индексу такому/сякому с привлечением `explain`?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже вы всё таки не очень понимаете как работают индексы. Самым простым объяснением будет предметный указатель в книге. Мы ищем определение какого-то термина. Быстро находим его в предметном указателе, а потом переходим на указанные там страницы и уже там ищем наше определение. А в противовес этому просмотр всей книги в поисках упоминаний нашего термина. Почувствуйте разницу во времени.

Базы данных обычно хранят информацию на страницах памяти, имеющих фиксированный размер. Например, SQL Server использует 8 килобайтные страницы (8192 байта), из которых под пользовательские данные доступно 8060 байт, а остальное служебная информация.

Для индексов SQL Server использует структуру, называемую сбалансированным деревом (B-tree). Дерево это состоит из корневого узла (root node), содержащего одну страницу, нескольких промежуточных уровней (intermediate levels), содержащих дополнительные страницы, и листового уровня (leaf level).
На страницах листового уровня находятся отсортированные элементы, соответствующие индексируемым данным. Число строк на странице индекса зависит от размера данных в индексируемых столбцах. SQL Server создаёт промежуточные уровни, используя первый элемент каждой страницы листового уровня и сохраняя элементы на странице вместе с указателем на страницу листового уровня. Аналогично формируется корневая страница.

[image: Сбалансированное дерево]

Допустим, нужно найти термин «SQL Server». На картинке приведён пример B-дерева. Сначала просматривается корневая страница. Мы знаем, что по алфавиту буква S находится между O и T. Таким образом надо переместиться на страницу O. Эта операция уже отсеяла треть данных. Теперь просматривая страницу промежуточно уровня мы находим значение S, после чего переходим уже непосредственно к странице листового уровня. Для поиска данных потребовалось прочитать три страницы индекса. Это утверждение будет верно для термина, начинающегося на любую букву. Т.е. сбалансированное дерево означает, что для нахождения данных потребуется прочитать всегда одинаковое количество страниц индекса.

Немного математики:

Предположим, что нам надо создать индекс для столбца с типом данных char(60). Для хранения каждой строки таблицы нужно будет 60 байт. Для хранения 100 строк нам понадобятся 6000 байт. Всё это уместится на одной странице памяти, так что в нашем индексе будет только одна страница, одновременно являющаяся корневой и листовой.
На одну страцу влезет 134 строки (8040 байт), а вот при добавлении 135-ой строки придётся создать две дополнительных страницы. Наше дерево будет содержать три страницы: корневую и две листовых. На первой странице листового уровня будет первая половина элементов, на второй - вторая. На корневой же странице у нас будет две строки с данными. Промежуточный уровень нам тут не нужен.

В таблицу можно добавить до 17956 строк, при этом число уровней индекса не изментися. Он будет состоять из 134 страниц по 134 элемента на каждой. На корневой странице будет так же 134 элемента. При добавлении в таблицу 17957-й строки надо бы добавить очередную листовую страницу и 135 элемент в корневую, но он туда уже не влезет, так что придётся добавить промежуточный уровень, содержащий две страницы. На первой странице будут находится начальные элементы первой половины страниц листового уровня, а на второй - начальные элементы второй половины страниц листового уровня. Корневая страница будет содержать две строки, соответствующие начальным значениям двух страниц промежуточного уровня.
Когда в таблицу будет добавлена 2406105-я строка, будет создан ещё один промежуточный уровень.

Таким образом, для поиска строки в таблице из примерно 2.5 миллионов строк, надо просмотреть всего три страницы данных. И только когда таблица перевалит за 300 миллионов, надо будет просматривать 4 страницы.

А если мы индексируем столбец с типом не char(60), а с типом int, который занимает 4 байта, то придётся просматривать только одну страницу до тех пор, пока не будет добавлена 2016 строка, или две страницы до тех пор, пока таблица не перевалит за 4 миллиона строк, или три страницы, пока количество записей не превышает 8 миллиардов.

B-tree - это самый распространённый тип индексов, но не единственный. В разных СУБД используются и другие типы под специфические задачи. Тема весьма обширная, и по ней есть много материалов.

Так вот, возвращаясь к самим индексам. Они бывают кластеризованными и некластеризованными. Кластеризованный индекс в таблице может быть только один и по сути он хранит в себе всю таблицу, т.е. на его листовом уровне лежат реальные данные таблицы. Классический случай - это когда в таблице есть поле ID и по нему создан кластеризованный индекс. Обычно, в нормально спроектированных реляционных БД, у каждой таблицы есть кластеризованный индекс, хотя бывают и исключения.

Некластеризованный индекс, как можно уже догадаться, хранит не все данные, зато хранит указатель на наш кластеризованный индекс, из которого можно выудить значения остальных столбцов.

Например, у нас есть таблица с физическими лицами, со столбцами ID, ФИО, дата рождения, ИНН. При этом у нас создан кластеризованный индекс по ID, и некластеризованный по ИНН. Мы хотим по заданному ИНН получить ФИО человека. Тогда мы ищем наш ИНН в некластеризованном индексе, находим там наши значения ID, соответствующие людям, а потом лезем в кластеризованный индекс и по нашим ID находим нужные ФИО. Если в таблице много строк, то разница между полным чтением всех записей и чтению индекса будет коллосальной. А если строк в таблице мало, то оптимизатор запросов может даже не использовать некластеризованный индекс по ИНН, т.к. решит, что ему быстрее просто прочитать всю таблицу. Тут очень много всяких тонкостей.

Ещё есть такое понятие, как покрывающий индекс. Например, у нас есть несколько ИНН, которые мы хотим проверить на существование в нашей таблице (описанной выше) и вывести только существующие в таблице ИНН. Тогда мы находим наши ИНН в некластеризованном индексе, а лезть в кластеризованный нам уже не надо, т.к. мы получили все нужные данные. Вот индексы, которые содержат в себе сразу все необходимые данные, и называются покрывающими.

Предположим, что в этой же таблице есть индекс по ФИО и дате рождения. А нам надо выбрать все записи, у которых дата рождения входит в заданный диапазон и вывести такие ФИО. Подходящего для фильтрации индекса у нас нет, но есть два индекса (наш по ФИО + ДР и кластеризованный) где имеются все необходимые данные для вывода. Что-то всё равно придётся читать полностью, и логичным выбором будет тот индекс, который имеет меньший размер. Соответственно, оптимизатор запросов выберет наш покрывающий индекс с ФИО + ДР и полностью его прочитает, вместо того чтобы читать всю таблицу (кластеризованный индекс). А если у нас в этой таблице ещё сотня каких-либо столбцов, то разница в размерах кластеризованного и нексластеризованного индексов будет отличатся в разы, если не в десятки раз.